# How to change the timepicker style?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

Hi I have a question about `TimePicker` in Android.
I've followed this [guide](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/) to create a time picker. It works however the problem is that I want to have a time picker which has scrollable option, like in this [one](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), rather than have you to press + or - to change the time.

I've looked around in the page and in the code and cannot understand how to change it into a scrollable picker.

Answer (score 1):

what i did is added library **app_compatv7**
and added

`<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>`

and add the theme to the `manifest.xml` so u will get new **`date picker`**